# How could I identify multiple commands for network application (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, networking, chat, protocols

I want to build a client-server-application for some practice. I started off with a simple chat which was not so hard to do. I'm also able to identify different commands by just simply split a String, e.g. "command:msg". But I think that may be a little inconvenient. So I'm wondering if there are better ways to realize that. And I stumbled over that side: 
http://www.javaworld.com/jw-01-1997/jw-01-chat.html?page=6
At the very end it says:

> An alternative, however, and much more elegant solution, is to abstract the protocol behind a set of stream classes. The specifics of header construction and insertion can be handled automatically by the stream classes, and the client is then left with much the same interface as before: Clients write messages to a stream, but instead of flushing the stream, they call a method that attaches appropriate headers and sends the encapsulated message.

I don't really know what is meant by that. Could somebody explain it, or even better, give me a code example. Perhaps there may are other ways to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to send messages encapsulated as the link you sent:

| ID | len | message contents |.

What they mean with "to abstract the protocol behind a set of stream classes" is to create classes that extend stream classes which will put the correct ID and length on the encapsulated message for you.

For example, for an extended PrintWriter where you send two kinds of message:

ID 1 - normal message.

ID 2 - error message.

```
class MyProtocolPrintWriter extends PrintWriter {

    public static final int NORMAL_MESSAGE = 1;
    public static final int ERROR_MESSAGE = 2;

    //put the constructor

    public void writeMessage(String message) {
        println(
            String.format(
            "%02x%02d%s", NORMAL_MESSAGE, message.length(), message));
    }

    public void writeErrorMessage(String message) {
        println(
            String.format(
            "%02x%02d%s", ERROR_MESSAGE, message.length(), message));
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh now I understand. But still I have to split up the string on the server side to look if it is an error message or a normal message. But since there is no separator how could it been done? I looked it up and I found MessageFormat. It contains a parser. Do you think that would be better for my purpose?

Comment: You can add a separator to the string, or make these header fields fixed size (as in the example,2 characters representing an hexadecimal). In the MessageFormat javadoc, there are a number of pitfalls on the parse() method. For simpler commands like the example, writing code to parse it is not difficult.

Comment: Ok I will see what I will do. I think I will write a little parser. Thx for your help :]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what one fairly successful chat network used for a protocol.

[Internet Relay Chat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat)

And here's a list of the commands that were implemented using the IRC protocol.

[List of Internet Relay Chat commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_commands)

You would implement these commands as a set of stream classes.  The user issues a command, and your stream class handles the specifics of the header construction and insertion into the stream.